# java increasing array stored value

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to know if the following code would increase the array value to the next array value every time it runs.

For e.g, on the first run, it stores value in `count[1]` of the array,
on the next run does it store the value in `count[2]`?

```
public static void getadminName(){
        String[] name= new String[20];
        for (int count=0;count<name.length;count++){
            name[count]= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter 
            admin's name:");
            String scount=Integer.toString(count);
            name[count]= scount+1;
            break;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: There are several problems with your code. Before giving any advice, can you elaborate on what you want to do ?

Comment: `name[count] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please enter admin's name:");` is redundant here. `name[count] = scount + 1;` overwrites the value

Comment: This is basically part of my program, where im running a program that will allow me to input a admin's name and go back to a main menu. However, i need to be able to store multiple admin's names, hence the need to store names in the array indexes 1, 2, 3, and so forth. The thing is that I will not be inputting all of the names at one shot. Also, may I know what are the problems with my code?

Comment: Just a small advice: Don't give `void` methods a name beginning with `get`, that is really disturbing and the only thing you get doing so will be trouble.

Comment: Ok thank you for ur suggestion!!!!

Comment: Alright. 
1- As @a625993 nicely said, you don't need the break statement to achieve your goal.
2- An extension of the above means you don't need the preceding 2 lines (with scount) since the for-loop already increments the count variable. They also overwrote the value previously entered by the user with "01" (scount is a String, so "0" + 1 = "01" and not "1" as you probably expected).
3- Lastly, your array of String will be erased when your method ends. I suggest you take a look at java.util.ArrayList and make it into an attribute.

Comment: Yes I've noted all that already. Well the only problem is that im not allowed to use Arraylists' for this.

Comment: Ok, I believe this is a school assignment of some sort. Giving you working code won't do you any help, so I advice you to read a bit about Object Oriented Programming (what is a Class, how to use attributes) and you will need to write what we could call a "cursor" (=a counter of how many names have been entered, this is the equivalent on what you tried to achieve with scount). I don't know which level you're at so it's difficult to give solid advices :/

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `break` statement and the code should do approximately what you want it to. Keep in mind that `name` is an array of strings, with twenty elements. When you do `name[count]`, you're referring to the `count`th element of that array, which is a String.

You notice that the `for` loop has three parts:

- `int count=0;` declares an integer named 'count', initialized to the value 0.
- `count < name.length` declares a "termination condition" - if, before executing the code inside the loop, this condition is false, then the loop ends. In this case, it runs until the variable `count` has a value greater than the length of the array `name`.
- `count++` is executed immediately *after* each iteration of the loop finishes.

The sum, in this case, is that you start with `count=0`, accessing the first element of `name`, and then you do things in the loop, and then `count` increases by one, and the code inside the loop runs again, until `count` is greater than the length of `name`.

The statement `break` specifically jumps out of the loop, regardless of whether it otherwise would have. That's what you don't want to do here - you want to continue looping.

Comment: Hmm I see, but what I want to do is to have a JOptionPane that only loops once, as i am creating a menu system that allows me to input names 1 at a time. I will not be inputting all of the names in at one shot.

Comment: I'd advise thinking on your own about how to handle that, and at which point in the program. Maybe, instead of using an array `string[]`, use an `ArrayList<String>`, which you can change at any time, or add to using `.add(item)`.

Comment: yes i've thought about that, problem is im not allowed to use arraylists'